# How to handle several events for the same Node in JavaFX using only one Event Handling class?

Tags: java, javafx

everyone. I've been searching for this question but I haven't found it here, so I'll guess it's really simple.

I'm creating a very simple application in JavaFX with a single button. Now I want to handle its events (like when it's pressed or when it's released), but when I see examples over the Internet, they all use anonymous classes (and a different class for each event), which makes the code dirty in my opinion. That's why I want to put the event handlers in a separate class and add them to the button.

The problem is that I don't know if I have to create a different class for every event, which I think isn't cool. So I came up with an idea. In the `handle()` method of the class I check which type of event is going on and process it.
This is the code

**Main class**

```
public class Main extends Application{

    Button button;
    PruebaEventHandler evhandler;

    public Main() {
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("h0i");

        button = new Button("Púlsame!");
        evhandler = new PruebaEventHandler();
        button.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, evhandler);
        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**EventHandler class**

```
public class PruebaEventHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>{
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event){
        if(event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED)){
            System.out.printf("Te cogí\n");
        }
        if(event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED)){
            System.out.printf("\nMe ha soltado!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is very inefficient or bad programming style, but is the only solution I've come up with so far. So I want to ask you if this is a good solution or, if there's a better one, shed your light on me! Thanks beforehand.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your implementation. You can use a switch statement or else if which is slightly more efficient. This question is probably off topic.

Answer (score -1):

There already exists a solution for this, which is creating a JavaFX-project with a FXML-file, Controller and also a Main class. IDEs like IntelliJ and NetBeans have support for letting you create a JavaFX-project, which automatically creates those files for you, but I'm not sure if you have to add a plugin to make it work, that I don't remember.

The FXML-file takes care of the GUI, for example placing a button in a scene, and the easiest way to use it is with a SceneBuilder, which Oracle has, and can also be integrated in your IDE.

If you use FXML you can direct buttons to methods inside your FXML-document, so you don't need to have anonymous classes for event handlers. Instead you make the button call a spesific method in your Controller-class.

Here are a couple of youtube-tutorials that showcase the basics of using JavaFX with FXML:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7BOH-Ll8_g
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMdjhuYSrqg